# How to View SEQUENCE Scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I view the script of the Sequence in SQL server. Because when I right-click, there's no 'View Sequence Script' menu option.

Please help.
Also, if you look at this image, there's no "SEQUENCE" option to 'generate-scripts'
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS you can script the sequence:

[image]

And in the "Generate Scripts" dialog they will be included if you choose to script the entire database:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, wondering how this passed the 'User Experience Software Testing' haha

Comment: I imagine it's because there's a long tail of object types.  Assemblies, Service Broker Queues, Services, Message Types, etc, Roles, Partition Functions, Partition Schemes. Synonyms, Types, Rules, Defaults, Plan Guides, Symmetric Keys, etc.